How would you show the following summation holds?
You can see here a list of different summations:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1342368p7293737
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \left[\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^2=\frac{B(1/4,1/4)}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}$$
Where B(x,y) is the beta function if someone's new. I wonder how would you prove this correspondence?
I have tried using identities of the hypergeometric function but I haven't calculated these kinds of sums before

Thanks. fixed...

You need to recognise the sum as an evalution of an Elliptic integral of the First Kind
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \left[\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^2 &=& \frac{2}{\pi} K(i) \\
& = & \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1+t^2)}}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sub $t=u^{1/4}$ and use $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}) \Gamma(\frac{3}{4}) = \pi \sqrt{2}$. The result will follow with $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi} $.

This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!
